# upload and filter for an age based on date on mongodb python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to upload users date on my database, doesn't matter which format Date or String. After that I want to query for users and do $lte and $gte on all dates to find a user with specific age range (example: 25-30), but the problem that I am currently having is this:

If I make a query on users that are aged 29, and for example I have

```
    User1: birthday: 21st May 1991 
    User2: birthday:  21st September 1991
```

and if today is for example 12th of June 2020, it gives me both users (User1 and User2), but it should give me only User1 because he has 29, and User2 is going to be 29 in a few months. Can anyone help me find a solution or propose one? Thank You!

My current Code:

```
    ageRangeFirst = 29
    ageRangeSecond = 31
    current_year = int(datetime.now().year)
    newFirstAge = current_year - ageRangeFirst
    newSecondAge = current_year - ageRangeSecond
    filter['dateOfBirth'] = {"$lte": '{}1231'.format(newFirstAge), "$gte": '{}0101'.format(newSecondAge)}
```

and on the database I save dates with this format as Strings:

```
   "dateOfBirth" : "19911201" //yyyyDDmm as String
```

I know that my current method should give a result that I am getting but I need a little bit better date and age queriing and management.

Thank You

Comment: Two things: 1st, you are not actually comparing dates, you are just comparing strings, and 2nd you are just subtracting the `year` to get the range, which is wrong.

Comment: @ngShravil.py I have solved the problem. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
    def addZeroToNumber(number):
        if number < 10:
          return '0{}'.format(number)
        else:
          return str(number)

    def checkTheAge():
        ageRangeFirst = int(request.get_json()['ageRangeFirst'])
        ageRangeSecond = int(request.get_json()['ageRangeSecond'])
        current_year = int(datetime.now().year)
        current_month = int(datetime.now().month)
        current_day = int(datetime.now().day)
        print(current_year, addZeroToNumber(current_month), addZeroToNumber(current_day))
        newFirstAge = current_year - ageRangeFirst
        newSecondAge = current_year - ageRangeSecond - 1

        date1Filter = datetime.strptime('{}-{}-{}T00:00:00.000Z'.format(newSecondAge, addZeroToNumber(current_month), addZeroToNumber(current_day)), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") #19
        date2Filter = datetime.strptime('{}-{}-{}T00:00:00.000Z'.format(newFirstAge, addZeroToNumber(current_month), addZeroToNumber(current_day)), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")  #17
        print(date1Filter)
        print(date2Filter)
        filter['dateOfBirth'] = {"$gte": date1Filter, "$lte": date2Filter}
```